# What could humanity do to survive airborn transmitted HIV for as long as possible?

Tags: internal-consistency, diseases, health

Here's the setting: In the year 2017 a team of scientists working for a terrorist organization create an airborne strain of HIV and release it over New York city. The news goes public IMMEDIATELY after its release.

My question being: What could the American government (as well as its citizens) do to ensure their survival for as long as possible

This Mutated Strain of HIV can survive on a surface for up to 68 hours (and up to 48 hours in temperatures between 15 degrees Fahrenheit and 45 degrees Fahrenheit.)

Comment: How many more of these  strange questions?  HIV is a disease that is not very resilient.   It survives because of  replication.   Now you have it surviving 68 hours on a surface.

Comment: I tried fixing it.

Comment: The main reason for me asking such a strange question is due to the fact that I've read about HIV and how it ****'s with the body (primarily how it infects the CD4 cells)

Comment: A resistant airborne HIV is going to to how give you insight on the disease?

Comment: I'm not looking for insight on the disease, I merely want to know what protective measures would be taken to prevent the spread of this particular disease

Comment: But the disease is not airborne so what do you expect to learn?

Comment: Any team of scientists who create an airborne strain of the HIV virus, doesn't matter if work for a terrorist organization, they are the greatest geniuses of biological science in human history. Grant them an unconditional amnesty and give them all the resources they need to work on any major health problem including anti-airborne-HIV vaccines. Shoot their former employers because they're not important.

Comment: @a4android  Really a disease that mutates on its own cannot live outside a host for more than a few seconds and any team of scientists who create an airborne strain?   Reality-check NO.

Comment: I merely want to know what measures would be taken to prevent the spread of a fictitious HIV strain

Comment: @Paparazzi My comment was made in jest. I know HIV is a fragile organism. Ergo, any bunch of guys who can create airborne HIV must be geniuses. It's what we call a joke.

Comment: @AnAspiringAuthor Sorry, I know that's what you want, but one of the logical consequences of your set-up appealed to my funny bone. Seriously, is this HIV strain spread like a respiratory illness, for example, like a flu. if so, then similar precautions would be taken. What made SARS so deadly was that expired matter containing the bacteria acted infectious agents. People left the infections on things they touched. Door knobs, lift buttons, and so forth.

Comment: This smells like an idea generation question.

Comment: While that wasn't my intent I do have a question. Is it okay to make an Idea Generation question on this site?

Comment: @AnAspiringAuthor Idea Generation questions are typically not good format for this site. In fact, we used to have a close reason for it specifically, but we now use "too broad" and "opinion based" instead of "idea generation" since those two are more specific.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out an airborne "HIV" disease.  Of course HIV as such could not reasonably be made airborne but what happens if you insert the HIV into a pathogen that is airborne and let it tag along for the ride?

Answer (score 7):

Just treat HIV like we already do. (The answer assumes that the airborne strain of HIV has been substantially toughened-up and its infectiousness increased - HIV doesn't last well outside of the body and isn't actually particularly infectious in its current form.)

With antiretroviral drugs the life expectancy with HIV is around the same as for HIV-negative people (and they're generally not infectious either); whilst the *cost* of treating everyone would be huge, even if the whole country was infected it'd only really cause deaths amongst those who didn't take the drugs. With so many people infected, resistant strains evolving would be the biggest problem.

Overall, HIV is probably not the ideal biological warfare agent - anthrax, ebola or smallpox would cause far more significant and scary effects.

Comment: I doubt that the cost of treating everyone would be *that* huge. On a mass scale, the pure synthesis costs of one drug aren't so much more expensive than another drug, the big driver in price is all the "fixed" costs, so economies of scale matter a lot. If you know that you need to produce a billion doses of HIV drugs, then you can most likely make it just a few times more expensive than a common vitamin pill.

Answer (score 5):

Like similar hypothetical questions, the devil is in the details.  First we'd find out what airborne means.  Under what conditions can the virus stay airborne?  The common cold can last 24 hours on a surface and still be infectious, while influenza only lasts 15 minutes.

In any case, we have plenty of well understood processes for minimizing the infection.  HIV isn't particularly infectious compared to the more dangerous pathogens which the terrorists chose.  It can be handled in biohazard level 2 enclosures, while more dangerous pathogens like Ebola are handled in much more frightening biohazard level 4 enclosures.  The typical flu prevention mechanisms would likely be more than sufficient.  One might choose to wear masks to avoid inhalation.

Not knowing the details, we can't say anything about what kills the virus, but generally speaking the UV of the sun is very effective at killing airborne contagions, so I'd focus mostly on how to sanitize indoors.  This is similar to the advice I'd give for the flu.

In the end, I'd expect most infected people to be those affected by the initial dispersal.  It takes a long time for HIV to gestate, so I think we'd have a decent timeline to realize what's happening and address it.

Answer (score 2):

Airborne HIV won't wipe out humanity. It would definitely reduce earth's population and bring an unimaginable suffering but no wipe out.

Here is how it probably would go down:

1.The mutated HIV is starting to infect people.

2.A view days or one or two weeks later, the massive increase in HIV cases, especially the ones where people would claim not to have had sex or any kind of needle injections, would lead to massive investigation by scientists, and global alarm systems would kick in.

3.Within one or two days after science joined our scenario, the news that HIV is now able to infect over normal every day contact, are available over the world. In the same time thanks to the snowball effect everyone that doesn't live isolated is infected.

4.Huge medication programs would start, we can't heal HIV but we can keep infected alive for many many years. In the same time the search for uninfected people would start, so we can isolate them and keep them clean.

5.Within the next decades HIV medication would improve and probably even a way to heal it would be found, if not the worlds population would slowly die away, till only the previously isolated would remain.

6.These survivors would start over and humanity would start to repopulate the world again.

Note: Point 5 and 6 could change due some evolution leading to a group of people that would be immune to HIV, even though this is relative unlikely, since HIV is changing much faster than humans could.,

Comment: I'm not sure this is what will happen. Most HIV positive people wont die much earlier than their HIV negative counterpart, if they receive treatment.  In fact, HIV isn't even deadly on its own, it will only get dangerous if it initiates AIDS in the host, which also isn't deadly on its own, but diminishes the hosts defenses against other diseases. Also, HIV positive people can still get children, this is not a species-threatening disease...

Comment: As far as I am aware, children from HIV positive mothers will also be HIV positive, and yes they won't die immediately, but a overall weakened population will sooner or later fall victim to another bigger disease.

Comment: Yes, Mother-Child transmission is one of the three major infection paths. But they will only fall victim to the diseases, if they aren't treated with the current (or more modern) blockers. HIV is not the same as AIDS. As of Wikipedia, "only" around half of the infected populace develops AIDS within 10 years. I'm not saying this won't have serious consequences for humanity, but as long as we are able to stop HIV from developing AIDS in the host, it's not really that deadly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a government that actually has it's act together:

**Immediately** impose an absolute quarantine on New York, imposed by the military--surround it with a free-fire zone, shoot anything that moves.  Tell everyone in New York to remain in place so long as that is consistent with remaining alive.

Then you send in the troops in MOPP-5 gear, the objective is to evacuate everyone from the quarantine zone and disperse them into a whole bunch of little camps in the southwest deserts.  Supplies are helicoptered in, nobody moves other than in biohazard gear.

Next comes a crash program to develop a test for the disease so you can figure out which camps are infected and which are clean--release everyone in camps identified as clean.  Once you know how many are infected build a city (using an existing one is unlikely to be workable due to the layout of the road network--you need to cut all external connections) and move the infected to that city.

Current HIV treatments will give them a reasonable life while they attempt to develop a cure.

Supplies will have to be brought in, the only export products will be digital (the city will no doubt become a major call center).

Answer (score 1):

**Aside from those infected in the initial spread, very few people will be infected by the mutated strain.**

As others have mentioned, HIV is a blood-borne pathogen. One of the most relevant effects of this is that even if it can survive for a significant amount of time outside of the body, it doesn't have a good mechanism for getting outside the body. I mean, when was the last time you coughed up blood? Or sneezed blood? It doesn't happen very frequently.

Also, even being able to survive outside the body does not mean that it would even be able to infect many people that way. Your body has a lot of defenses against bacteria and viruses, and HIV isn't used to dealing with them. It won't be in as high of concentrations when it is airborne, and oral sex is already low risk for transmitting HIV.

Taking these two together, it's unlikely that many people would actually get infected. If you want you could, of course, handwave these issues away and say that it is as infectious as the common cold or the flu or measles or whatever you want. However, at that point you've changed the virus so much from what it currently is that there is no way for us to give you a good answer to your question - it would no longer be HIV, it would be a virus made of handwavium with unexplainable abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Quarantine of the exposed, HEPA filters for those inside, face shields and masks for those out and about. I like the idea of vaporizing or misting a liquid to capture and suspend the virus in the liquid on a city scale.

Comment: A bit short to be a full answer.

Comment: "Vaporizing or misting a liquid to capture and suspend" - what do you mean? as a tool to spread it or to defend against it? if its the former, its called "making an aerosol". I have never heard of the latter

Answer (score 0):

Reality-check - NO

A team of scientist is not going to create an airborne HIV.

HIV is blood-borne pathogen that cannot live outside a host for more than a few seconds.